# Use a variable in preg_grep matching in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I use a variable name in preg_grep?

I'm iterating over an array of file names and trying to match to the file name in the format of "Some File-0.png", "Some File-1.png" so on and so forth.

Here's what I'm using.

`$arrayRet=preg_grep("/$filename-\d*.png/",$ret);`

I know the $ character is a special pattern character but I don't know how to escape it or if that's even the problem.

I've tried this but to no avail.

```
$pattern = "/".$filename."-\d*.png/";
$arrayRet=preg_grep($pattern,$ret);
```

EDIT: $ret returns a list of files such as this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References - Government-0.png
    [1] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References - Government-1.png
    [2] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References - National-0.png
    [3] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References - National-1.png
    [4] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References - National-2.png
    [5] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References-0.png
    [6] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Client References-1.png
    [7] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Company Profile-0.png
    [8] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Company Profile-1.png
    [9] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Corporate Overview - Short Version-0.png
    [10] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Presentation\thumbs\...\Corporate Overview - Short Version-1.png
```

Note - I've added ellipses to shorten the path.

$filename would be `Client References - Government`, `Client References - National`, `Client References` and so on.

Comment: `"$filename"` interpolates the variable contents, the `$` does not become an anchor. Your sample filenames do not need escaping, but anchoring the regex `^` `$` might be sensible, or overriding case-sensitivity. In this case `fnmatch()` and a loop/array_filter callback might be an alternative. Also enable `error_reporting` and elaborate on the "to no avail" part.

Comment: @mario Thank you. I tried anchoring the regex with `$arrayRet=preg_grep("/^$filename-\d*.png/",$ret);` and nothing changed. I also enabled `error_reporting` and the regex still returns an empty array with no errors.

Comment: Well, then it didn't match anything. Only you can tell why, because you haven't revealed what your `$ret` array actually contains.

Comment: @mario Ok I've added the contents of $ret, and the value of $filename for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_quote` to escape all special regex meta characters:

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($filename, '/') . '-\d*.png/';
$arrayRet = preg_grep($pattern, $ret);
```